# Clicking on "more hot questions" doesn't expand and site jumps to top

Tags: bug, new-nav

If I click on a tab, and then on the "more hot questions" link to expand the list of HNQs, then it doesn't expand and the site jumps to the top.

This only happens when I click on any tab, except for the "Home" tab when I first visit the site. If I go to another tab, and then reclick on the "Home" tab, the error still persists.

Here is the relevant JavaScript error. I'm on Chrome 54.0.2840.71 (64-bit):

```
Uncaught TypeError: StackExchange.helpers.bindShowMoreHotNetworkQuestions is not a function(…)
a                       @   full.en.js?v=f5a0869a3a0c:4
onLoadSucceeded         @   full.en.js?v=f5a0869a3a0c:4
onLoadSucceeded         @   full.en.js?v=f5a0869a3a0c:4
(anonymous function)    @   full.en.js?v=f5a0869a3a0c:3
i                       @   jquery.min.js:2
fireWith                @   jquery.min.js:2
e.(anonymous function)  @   jquery.min.js:2
i                       @   jquery.min.js:2
fireWith                @   jquery.min.js:2
y                       @   jquery.min.js:4
c                       @   jquery.min.js:4
```

If I wasn't clear enough, here are the steps to reproduce:

1. Go to [stackoverflow.com](http://stackoverflow.com)
2. Click on the "Voted" tab (you could also click on any other tab)
3. You will now see the above JavaScript exception
4. Clicking on "more hot  questions" results in the page jumping to the top